# Tracking approval reassign in Power Automate

Tags: approval, power-automate

I have is a system that needs to start an approval process sending an approval to a person listed in a list item (the reviewer), this reviewer can acknowledge it, reject it or reassign it.

If they havent responded in 7 days I need to send a reminder email and update the item status to Overdue

So I built it out as a
Create approval
Wait for response
Update list item on  response

and had a parallel task set up with the wait for of delay 7 days check status and email again if not complete

My problem comes with if User A reassigns it to user B at day 2 I cant seem to see that within the flow for the Overdue email

Is there a way to see the current assigned approver(s) to an approval?